# Using Blender to animate physical (real world, non-Blender) lights

Tags: python, interface

I am thinking about using Blender as a way to animate a 3 dimensional array of lights in physical space. I thought I could set up a 3D mesh of spheres and animate the color and intensity of those spheres, values of which I would then send to the real world via OSC or some other protocol using Python. Is this a feasible way to do this? I could just use a lighting program but I would like the flexibility of having an object made up of the pixels (spheres) animated. I wanted to ask here before I go down this rabbit hole as I'm not a Blender user but see it as a great potential interface for this project. Any opinions on this or anyone know of similar projects/attempts at this. Thanks for any insights.

Comment: This is a very interesting project, It would be fantastic to develop a cross talk between Blender/Python and the MIDI protocol (widely used in Music and Lighting production): there would be a lot of controllers, for data input, lots of hardware responding to the instructions, lots of sequencers to run the programmings! I'm not a developer but I'd would like to get in touch. joshsanfelici@gmail.com

Comment: Consider that Blender works with mathematical points in a 3D space (not pixels). Every point has a location (3 values: XYZ coordinate), a rotation (difference from starting 000 rotation) and scale (difference from 111 default scale). Then every point can be an object, a bone, an empty, etc.. having others attributes (materials, color, UV (2Dimensionals) projections, intensity of some parameters, custom properties, etc..).

Comment: If you have a mac, try quartz composer. Processing linked with Arduino could also work. Both quartz and processing have the 3D rendering capabilities that you need for this project so it should be simpler to implement with them.

Comment: [Here is sort of the opposite direction](http://www.blendernation.com/2016/10/27/arduino-blender-animated-movements/), but interesting nonetheless. I don't know how he does it, but it's definitely possible in that sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointers. I considered Processing but I really wanted to use a program dedicated to animation so I could use it's tools.  @joshsanfelici I think if anything rather than MIDI it would probably be useful to use DMX or OSC as an output protocol at least for my purposes. Thanks for the link to the puppet . Quite interesting. For those of you interested in this thread I found this link which also offers some insights. [link](http://funkboxing.com/wordpress/?p=1308)